# Is there an R function for nested ifelse functions?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to combine many variables to make a dummy variable for whether somebody belongs to one occupation category, using ifelse. I was wondering if there was a function to simplify this code and make it easier to repeat going forward.
For example, my code is currently:

```
occupation_blue_collar <- ifelse(occupation=="Blue Collar", T, 
                          ifelse(occupation =="Blue Collar and Ex-Military", T, 
                          ifelse(occupation == "Blue Collar and Non-military Government", T,
                          ifelse(occupation== "Blue Collar and School Student", T,
                          ifelse(occupation== "Blue Collar and University Student", T,
                          ifelse(occupation== "Blue Collar and White Collar", T,       
                                        F))))))
```

I have to do this over many variables and many categories, so I was hoping there was a way to simplify. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your `ifelse` statement by using `stringr::str_detect` in your test expression -

```
ifelse(str_detect(occupation, “Blue Collar”, TRUE, FALSE))
```

If you have many variables then `dplyr::case_when` would be better -

```
case_when(str_detect(occupation, “Blue Collar”) ~ TRUE,
          str_detect(occupation, “White Collar) ~ TRUE,
          TRUE ~ FALSE)
```

Comment: Or even `grepl("^Blue Collar", x)`

Answer (score 1):

See [case_when](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) which should meet your needs

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cg = case_when(carb <= 3 ~ "low",
                        carb > 3  ~ "high"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`occupation=="Blue Collar" | occupation =="Blue Collar and Ex-Military" | ...`

Where `|` is the "or" operator.

Since you seem to have a lot of repeating words (i.e. "Blue Collar") you should look into regex to see if you can automate some of this repetition.

Answer (score -2):

Few different ways to address this concern, but I think the easiest way to do this is to just use OR logic in your ifelse statement

`ifelse(occupation == "Blue Collar" | occupation == "Blue Collar and Ex-Military" | occupation == "Blue Collar and Non-military Government" | occupation == "Blue Collar and School Student" | occupation == "Blue Collar and University Student", "T", "F")`

However, if you have to do this many times across occupations, there is an even better way to do this. I would create a csv with the header of occupations_blue_collar, and fill the column with all the possible columns you want. Then read in the csv, and use
`ifelse(occupation %in% df$occupations_blue_collar, "T", "F")`. Rinse and repeat for your other occupations!

Edit: as @markus has pointed out, if all of the values you want to be in occupations_blue_collar have the words 'blue collar' in them, then `ifelse(grepl("blue collar", occupation), 'T', 'F')` would be the most efficient way to process this! To filter out 'blue collar and white collar', you can use `ifelse(grepl('blue collar', occupation) & occupation != 'blue collar and white collar', 't', 'f')` or ifelse(grepl('blue collar', occupation) & !grepl('white collar', occupation), 't', 'f')`

Edit 2: changing || to | as @wusel suggested.

Comment: Why not `grepl("^Blue Collar", x)` ?

Comment: Be careful about `||` since it is not vectorized!

Comment: `grepl` returns a logical vector, so no need for `ifelse` (which is not very efficient btw). Simply `grepl("^Blue Collar", x)`. And instead of multiple `|`s and `==`s you might consider to use `%in%`

Comment: I don't think the OP intended to assign `"T"` as a string, they intended to assign `TRUE` as a logical data type